# On accident- part of speech

Tags: grammar

Is 'on' still a preposition in the phrase 'on accident', or 'on purpose'? I have noticed Americans say 'on accident', where I would say 'by accident'.

Comment: _On_ and _by_ are still prepositions.

Comment: Wouldn't by be a substitute of sorts for through. I was married by a preacher. .. by wouldn't be a preposition there. I am all confused now :)

Comment: @JohnLawler Do Americans really say *I did it on accident*? If so, I've never heard it.

Comment: I've never heard "on accident" by Americans (being one myself).  We say "by accident" such as "I knocked over the lamp by accident".  Could it be a regional thing?

Comment: 'by' ***is*** a preposition there. Have a look in a dictionary. https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=by+definition

Comment: @KristinaLopez - I think it is some kind of wordplay judging by this for example: You're Not Here on Accident. You're Here on Assignment! https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=evqcPvro62AC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22on+accident%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAGoVChMIgbLPhO69yAIVRrIUCh2DsQ37#v=onepage&q=%22on%20accident%22&f=false

Comment: I think it is broader than that. I thought it was something my wife did. Then found out it was more widespread

Comment: I've heard "*on* accident" quite a bit in upstate New York.

Comment: In my experience, "by accident" is a lot more common than "on accident" in U.S. usage—but "accidentally" may be even more common than "by accident."

Comment: A Google search of "on accident" returns a bunch of articles on the prepositional variation of this phrase.

Comment: I agree with @Sven.

Comment: @JohnLawler This is the first time I have ever encountered *on accident*, and clearly that is the case with some Americans too. Would the fact that it exists in pockets, such as upstate New York, as Silenus has indicated, be the kind of thing that would be due to the fact that an area was originally settled by non-English-speaking communities e.g. Germans or Dutch? One area where your English strongly diverges from our variety is in the use of some prepositions. Has the influence of different European languages on the development of American English been studied and documented?

Comment: *On accident* is part of my natively acquired AmE, though I was taught not to say it pretty early on.  It's not wordplay, it's just a non-standard expression presumably formed by analogy to *on purpose*.  FWIW, I grew up in Chicagoland, and I must have picked it up from other speakers there.

Comment: @Silenus I also heard this a lot when I was growing up in upstate NY - maybe it's a regionalism like pop / soda / coke etc.?

Comment: @WS2, The idea that some regional variations are wholly or partly influenced by the immigrant languages of that area is an interesting one! I've never seen any particular cases made. Maybe you should write this up as a question!

Comment: Related: [Is it correct to say “on accident” instead of “by accident”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215), [Why do we say “On purpose” vs “By accident”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334455)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is on still a preposition in the phrase on accident, or on purpose? I have noticed Americans say on accident, where I would say by accident.

Yes, it is still a preposition. It's just the wrong preposition!

I can find one example in print, i.e.

[You're Not Here on Accident. You're Here on Assignment!](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=evqcPvro62AC&printsec=frontcover&dq=on%20accident&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=on%20accident&f=false)

However that seems to be a form of wordplay. Where have you seen or heard the phrase 'on accident' being used. Did you hear it in everyday conversation? In what kind of sentence?

Comment: Definitely correct on the preposition front. I don't know that on is wrong so much as different usage.

Comment: @reabow: I think given the fact that *happened **on** accident* is [so rare by comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=happened+on+accident%2Chappened+by+accident&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chappened%20by%20accident%3B%2Cc0) with *happened **by** accident*, it's not unreasonable to say the former is quite simply "wrong" if it's not part of a deliberate wordplay.

Comment: I think the premise is that if a group of native English speakers use a phrase, it is correct. This is even if it differs from standard English. I think you will find it widespread enough to meet this criteria.

Comment: @reabow - This is a perennial problem on this and other English language sites. There are two main schools of thought. Some of us believe that there is such a thing as 'correct' English and that it is to be found in dictionaries and grammar books. Others of our number think that correctness is determined by a sufficient population of speakers even if their speech does not conform to said reference books -- or any reference books at all. If you think it is widespread then that is fair enough. I think you need some evidence of that spread though. So far I haven't seen enough to convince me.

Comment: @chasely Now that I am alert to it, I have heard it a few times.  It is definitely more of a hunch.  Correct English is a form of hegemony in my view.  It limits inclusion and diversity.  Languages change and evolve, and we are powerless to stop them.  (Much as I might rile inwardly when people say less when they meant fewer :)

Comment: Or say 'rile inwardly' when they mean 'rail'? ;-)  [Sorry, I couldn't resist -- it's not a dig!]

Comment: They both work. rile
verb
1.
informal
make (someone) annoyed or irritated.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can't work out what "quite simply wrong" in your comment means.  You mean it's just a lie that some people say "on accident"?  Or anyone who says that is not speaking English?  Or is not a person you approve of?  Or what?

Comment: @Greg Lee: Given the parallel to *on purpose*, I guess it stands to reason there will be the occasional ***on accident*** and ***by purpose***, but I very much doubt there's any dialect/"linguistic community" where those versions would be considered "locally standard/normal usage". Google Books has just 16 instances of [*it happened on accident*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22it+happened+on+accident%22#q=%22it+happened+on+accident%22&tbm=bks&start=10), compared to about 4,370 results for the standard version, so I don't think "wrong" is putting it too strongly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I don't see there an answer to the question I asked you.  Unless you mean that "quite simply wrong" means "is seldom written in books".  Is that what you mean? Or "is locally standard"?  ("On accident" sounds fine, to me, though I wouldn't use it in a formal setting.  I consider my speech to be standard.)

Comment: @reabow - Off-topic discussion: But 'rile' is transitive. You cannot rile without a direct object. Instead of, "I rile inwardly", you would have to say 'I rile myself inwardly'. It's just the same with its synonym 'to annoy'. You wouldn't presumably say, "I annoy inwardly"

Comment: @chaslyfromUK You are indeed correct.  It is transitive, and there should be an object.  I thought I could use it like stew, or boil which would be intransitive.

Answer (score 1):

I see in various comments people saying confidently that "on" is a preposition in "on accident" and "on purpose", but I don't see anyone giving evidence that this is actually true.  How can you tell?  Maybe it's a prefix, fulfilling a function similar to that of "-ally" in "accidentally" (which, after all, means "on accident").

The "accident" inside "accidentally" can't be preceded by an article or modified by an adjective, *"the-complete-accident ally", naturally, because you can't go inside a word and modify part of it, or put an article with part of it.  So lets test "on accident": *"on the accident", *"on complete accident" are not acceptable.  The "accident" inside "on accident" is not behaving as we would expect it to, if it were an independent word.  That is evidence that "on accident" is not two independent words, even though it is written with an internal space in English orthography.

Notice that "by accident" is different, since "by complete accident" is fine, and similarly "by an accident of circumstances".

I will be looking forward to seeing some evidence from those of you who thought it was so obvious that the "on" in "on accident" and "on purpose" was a preposition.

Comment: Uh, "on accident" isn't a standard American English expression (as the comments above strongly indicate).  So your above arguments are just jaw flapping.

Comment: @HotLicks, your comment is not relevant to the question or my answer.

Comment: Greg, the fact (if it be such) that ' on accident' is not actually a phrase in normal English is relevant to the question, and does invalidate your answer.

Comment: @TimLymington, please explain to us how the fact that "on accident" does not occur in some standard dialects tells us whether "on" in the expression is a preposition.  If you review the question, you will notice that it does not ask whether the expressions are standard.

Comment: @GregLee - do you consider *'on demand'* a similar case, bearing in mind that there's no "demandly" equivalent to "accidentally" and "purposely".

Comment: @JHCL, I don't know about *'on demand'*.  I've just run through some tests to see whether the noun or putative preposition can be modified separately, and I get mixed results.

Answer (score 0):

My kids say "on accident" all the time. It drove me crazy at first, until I heard many of their friends using the same terminology.

A recent study by a bona fide linguist concludes that this is indeed generational:

> A high-school English teacher asks which is correct: *It happened on accident*, or *It happened by accident*? A survey by linguist Leslie Barratt at Indiana State University indicates that most people born after 1990 use *on accident*, and weren’t even aware that *by accident* was proper, while those born before 1970 almost always say *by accident*.

You can hear the podcast at [this website](http://www.waywordradio.org/on-accident-or-by-accident/).

[Another grammar site](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/grammarlogs2/grammarlogs337.htm) addressed this issue more than a decade ago, back in 1999:

> I don't know where "on accident" comes from. My kids used to use this phrase all the time. "It's not my fault. It happened 'on accident'!" I thought it was a regional expression, something they picked up in southern New England, but it crops up all over. "By accident" is certainly the more common, standard expression. The preposition "on" seems to have imperialist tendencies, creeping into places — "standing on line, waiting on the bus" — where "in" and "for" were doing their job quite nicely.

This seems to be a case where the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=happened+by+accident%2Chappened+on+accident&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) isn't going to support the younger generation, but, like it or hate it, the language appears to be evolving anyway – perhaps [on accident](http://www.more.com/lifestyle/childrens-lies-mom-it-happened-accident).