# Why do we say "On purpose" vs "By accident"?

Tags: prepositions

My 12 year old deserves credit for this question.

He asked "Why do we say 'by accident' but not 'by purpose' "

I was stumped - this is an embarrassing situation!    Searching left me cold.   The nearest result I could find was [Is it correct to say "on accident" instead of "by accident"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215/is-it-correct-to-say-on-accident-instead-of-by-accident) but this is a different question.

We also say "by chance" rather than "on chance".

So, can anyone help me be Dad-who-knows-all again?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a question of idiomatic usage,   ***[on purpose](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=purpose)*** is an idiomatic expression which dates back to the latter part of the 16th century:.

> - "by design" is ***attested from 1580s.***

Its earlier foorm  was ***"of purpose (early 15c.)"***  probably from the French "de propos".

(Etymonline)

Note also the expression : ***[accidentally on purpose](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/accidentally-on-purpose.html):***

Origin

> - The first printed record of this phrase that I can find is from The history of the famous preacher Friar Gerund de Campazas, by José Francisco de Isla, 1772:
>
>   - *Tell us what is Modesty of Voice, for you happened accidentally on purpose to drop this word, and I don't rightly know what it signifies.*

The Phrase Finder