# What is a word for an action that you did but did not mean to do?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

So, I am reading this book called *Animal Farm* where this stallion named Boxer is forgets he has iron-shod hoofs and he gives this stable-lad a blow to the head, which knocked him lifeless, though he had no intention of doing so. What one word, if there is any, would describe that sort of action... one that you did not mean to do?

Comment: I'm not sure there is one word to describe such an action.  But there are a few ways we talk about this.  Killing the stable boy was an **unintended consequence.**  He killed the stable boy **on accident.** He **didn't mean to** kill the stable boy.

Comment: @KumaAram Please see this post: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/215/18655

Answer (score 4):

[**Inadvertent**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/inadvertent): done or happening unintentionally

Comment: Please fix the spelling.

Comment: @JLG - It was inadverdent.

Answer (score 0):

A mishap, an accident, a contretemps.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).